# Converting a serial number into date

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, formatting

In an Excel sheet I will receive the data, which in turn I need to upload it to SQL server and then implement the logic.

I have received a date field `--[Due Date]` as number ex: `-.40317`. In Excel if you right click it and then format it to a date. It will show the correct date as `19.05.2010`.

So after uploading the file as it is. I have used,

```
SELECT (dateAdd(day,[Due Date],'1900-01-01')) FROM table1.
```

Assuming that Excel counts the days from `01-01-1900`. So I am adding the number `--[Due Date]` Which should give me the proper formatted date..

But this returns me a value of `2010-05-21 00:00:00.000`.

Can you please help me whether by assumption that Excel counts from `01-01-1900` is wrong, or the procedure that I have used is wrong to give such a value.

Comment: I think what Excel is doing is converting the Date into an int representation. Have you tried to cast it directly?

Comment: Thanku for the reply. I have tried CAST as well. This is also returns originaldate+2 days. For ex:- for this 40319 it should return 21.05.2010. But returns 23.05.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393050/conversion-of-integer-to-datetime-differs-to-vb6) a while ago - it wasn't talking about Excel but VB6, hence I'm not suggesting this question is a duplicate. However, the answer I think is the same.

Date 0 in SQL is 01/01/1900. 
Date 0 in VB6 is 30/12/1899, 2 days earlier - that explains the difference. 

So I believe Excel to be the same.

In Excel, I entered 0 in a cell and formatted the cell as a date - which displayed (weirdly IMO) 0/1/1900. I've had a quick look to find another reference that answers this definitively, but haven't managed to find one.

**Edit:**
Pulling in links that were given to me in my question (that do relate to Excel):
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=46561
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html

Comment: +1 Thanku very much. That helped me to understand why there is 2 days diference.

Answer (score 1):

As someone said, convert it to a better format in Excel first.

Most likely Excel and SQL Server have different takes on how many days there is from 1900-01-01. I think Excel had some old quirk with 1900 being a leap year or not (For 1-2-3 compatability?) so there's one of the extra days. The other I don't know, perhaps it starts counting on 1900-01-02 or Excel actually starts on 1900-01-00 or something? ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to subtract two days from "excel date number" to convert it into "MS SQL date".

```
select dateadd(day,-2, 36526)
```

**Explanation:**

Excel uses 0-jan-1900 as its begin date while SQL server uses 1-jan-1900, so to convert excel date to MS SQL date you can do something like this

```
 select dateadd(day,-1, 36526)
```

But wait, earlier version of excel has bug and calculating 1900 as a leap year but in fact it was not a leap year. Current version still calculate the same (I assume due to backward compatibility. [Or use the 1904 Date System rather than 1900 date system](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180162/en-us)). So we need to subtract 1 more day to fix this problem.

So our final query to convert excel date number to SQL Server would be

```
select dateadd(day,-2, 36526)
```

Comment: On SQL 2012 and I bet 2014 this displays 1 day off, I used select dateadd(day, -2, 40317) to get the proper date. This might have to do with the leap year. Not sure really, I need to keep researching.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Usman, I tried your solution it worked fine but if I try to use the same line with column name in place of that number it is failing and giving me an error like `Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

example : `select dateadd(day,-2,IssueDate) FROM myTable`

Answer (score 0):

Excel provides functions which will convert dates to strings (try the functions list or Google). This should obviate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not only Excel 0 date is 1/0/1900, but it seems that Microsoft thought that 1900 was a leap yaer that's why we could find a 02/29/1900 in Excel which value is 60. But year 1900 like every century year (except the multiple of 400) was NOT a leap year, that's why you must substract 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

datetime example:

```
select cast(44391.7468126852 as datetime) - 2
```